# How to choose the value of the slope compensation?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, stability

I do not understand how RICHTEK as chosen its slope compensation. The article is [here](https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN028?sc_lang=en). The parameters of the buck are the following:

- Vin = 12 V
- Iout = 3 A
- Lout = 10 uH
- Fsw = 340 kHz
- Vout = 3.3 V

The slope compensation is chosen as:

[image]

Which gives:

$$Se=0,507*340kHz = 172 kV/s$$

The downslope is:

$$S_{off}=\frac {V_{out}}{L_{out}}=\frac {3V3}{10u} = 330mA/µs$$

RICHTEK choosed a sense resistor of 192 mΩ. So it gives:

$$S'_{off} = R_{sense}*S_{off} = 192m*330mA/µs = 63mV/µs = 63kV/s $$

Normally, the slope compensation should be equal to the half of the current downslope of the inductor seen by the sense resistor. So Se should be equal to:

$$S_{e}=\frac {S'_{off}}{2}=\frac {63kV360}{2} = 31kV/s$$

It is not the case. Where is my error? Is it overdamped?

Thank you

Comment: Richtek uses the expression derived by Ridley in his current-mode-controlled model: \$m_c=1+\frac{S_e}{S_n}\$. If \$m_c=1.5\$ then you have the 50% you talk about but, usually, the amount of external slope is evaluated by assessing the quality factor \$Q_p\$ of the subharmonic poles located at \$\frac{F_{sw}}{2}\$. \$S_e\$ is then computed to bring \$Q_p\$ to 1, leading to an external ramp slope different than 50%.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)